# Is there any difference between IS NULL and =NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am surprised to see that IS NULL and =NULL are yielding different results in a select query. What is difference between them? When to use what. I would be glad if you can explain me in detail.

Comment: Check out the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29) for additional information.

Comment: This is a dup of a number of questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843451/why-does-null-null-evaluate-to-false-in-sql-server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does NULL = NULL evaluate to false in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843451/why-does-null-null-evaluate-to-false-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`= NULL` is always `unknown` (this is piece of 3 state logic), but `WHERE` clause treats it as `false` and drops from the result set. So for `NULL` you should use `IS NULL`

Reasons are described here: [Why does NULL = NULL evaluate to false in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843451/why-does-null-null-evaluate-to-false-in-sql-server)

Comment: It is not `false`. It is `unknown`. If it was false then `NOT(X = NULL)` would be `true`. This is not the case. SQL uses 3 valued logic.

Comment: @Martin Smith i know about 3 state logic. but `WHERE` clause treats `unknown` as `false` and drop off from result set.

Answer (score 15):

To add to existing answers, it depends whether you have ANSI_NULLS on or not, when using "= NULL".

```
-- This will print TRUE
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;
IF NULL = NULL
    PRINT 'TRUE'
ELSE
    PRINT 'FALSE'

-- This will print FALSE
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
IF NULL = NULL
    PRINT 'TRUE'
ELSE
    PRINT 'FALSE'
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a difference between `IS NULL` and `= NULL` and this is because of the three-valued-logic of SQL:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Three-valued_logic_.283VL.29

Extract of a relevant paragraph:

> **Challenges**
>
> Null has been the focus of controversy and a source of
>   debate because of its associated three-valued logic (3VL), special
>   requirements for its use in SQL joins, and the special handling
>   required by aggregate functions and SQL grouping operators. Computer
>   science professor Ron van der Meyden summarized the various issues as:
>   "The inconsistencies in the SQL standard mean that it is not possible
>   to ascribe any intuitive logical semantics to the treatment of nulls
>   in SQL." Although various proposals have been made for resolving these
>   issues, the complexity of the alternatives has prevented their
>   widespread adoption.

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. Include the relevant information from the link here, so that if the target site disappears, your answer will still be useful. (This is better as a comment.)