# SQL is null and = null

Tags: sql, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is “=null” and “ IS NULL”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749044/what-is-null-and-is-null)
>   [Is there any difference between IS NULL and =NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777230/is-there-any-difference-between-is-null-and-null)

What is the difference between

```
where x is null
```

and

```
where x = null
```

and why does the latter not work?

Comment: Because the result of any arithmetic comparison with NULL is also NULL, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such comparisons - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: 'is null' works as a function as well. Check out: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Comment: Which dbms are you using? There are several product specific answers below, getting upvotes.

Comment: This is already asked question and various solution available , https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/understanding-the-difference-between-is-null-and-null

Answer (score 191, accepted):

In SQL, a comparison between a `null` value and any other value (including another `null`) using a comparison operator (eg `=`, `!=`, `<`, etc) will result in a `null`, which is considered as `false` for the purposes of a where clause (strictly speaking, it's "not true", rather than "false", but the effect is the same).

The reasoning is that a `null` means "unknown", so the result of any comparison to a `null` is also "unknown". So you'll get no hit on rows by coding `where my_column = null`.

SQL provides the special syntax for testing if a column is `null`, via `is null` and `is not null`, which is a special condition to test for a `null` (or not a `null`).

Here's some SQL showing a variety of conditions and and their effect as per above.

```
create table t (x int, y int);
insert into t values (null, null), (null, 1), (1, 1);

select 'x = null' as test , x, y from t where x = null
union all
select 'x != null', x, y from t where x != null
union all
select 'not (x = null)', x, y from t where not (x = null)
union all
select 'x = y', x, y from t where x = y
union all
select 'not (x = y)', x, y from t where not (x = y);
```

returns only 1 row (as expected):

```
TEST    X   Y
x = y   1   1
```

See this running on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d885b/1)

Comment: Given `NULL = NULL` is not `true`, we can conclude that the semantic meaning of `null` is different on either side of the `=` operator. LHS it is a concept, RHS it a predicate. (i.e. "being unknown" vs "is unknown"). These, by nature, are not equal to each other. ▮

Comment: No, the semantic meaning of NULL is just "unknown". It is not a value, and cannot be reasoned about as if it were. The reason NULL = NULL is not true is because you cannot compare things you have no knowledge of, which is what NULL represents. Is the number of stars in the universe equal to the number of grains of sand? Who knows? The answer is NULL (unknown).

Answer (score 97):

It's important to note, that **NULL doesn't equal NULL**.

`NULL` is not a value, and therefore cannot be compared to another value.

`where x is null` checks whether x is a null value.

`where x = null` is checking whether x equals NULL, which will never be true

Comment: Null is a value, it's just unknown value. Like in programming languages variable can have value null. Furthermore you can compare if( varA != null). In sql though its treated differently like you pointed out.

Comment: @broadband: null is not a value, just like infinity is not a number. It's more of a philosophical thing though... Yes, you can assign "null" to a variable, but that just means you are unsetting or resetting that variable. 0 or "" would be a value, but null effectively means "this variable has no value".

Comment: @Sygmoral internally when you write in c# string a = null, it means that you are setting value `null` to variable `a`. But interpretation for programer is like you said: 'this variable has no value'. Further more in sql null can have multiple interpretations or three-valued logic.

Comment: @Sygmoral if you look at Bohemian answer it states: `In SQL, a comparison between a null value`. He's also writing about value.

Answer (score 9):

First is correct way of checking whether a field value is `null` while later won't work the way you expect it to because `null` is special value which does not equal anything, so you can't use equality comparison using `=` for it.

So when you need to check if a field value is `null` or not, use:

```
where x is null
```

instead of:

```
where x = null
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that equality is something that can be absolutely determined. The trouble with `null` is that it's inherently unknown. `Null` combined with any other value is `null` - unknown. Asking SQL "Is my value equal to `null`?" would be unknown every single time, even if the input is `null`. I think the implementation of `IS NULL` makes it clear.