# Criteria API find 'NULL'

Tags: jpa, null, criteria-api

The following is an extract from a larger Criteria Query:

```
...
Expression literal = builder.literal((String) "%" + value + "%");

List<Predicate> globalPredicate = new ArrayList<>();

globalPredicate.add(builder.equal(subject.get(Subject_.email), literal));

predicates.add(builder.or(globalPredicate.toArray(new Predicate[globalPredicate.size()])));  
...
```

There is a condition that exists where I explicitly want to pass in `null` and find the `Subject_.email` who are `null`. I tried passing in `null` and found that the criteria API wants a nullLiteral(). I tried conditionally replacing *literal* with nullLiteral() when it was appropriate but then I get nothing returned at all.

What is the best practice way of creating a query that will match `null` values for the specified attribute in the DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally use [`Expression#isNull()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Expression.html#isNull%28%29). Using your example:

```
globalPredicate.add(subject.get(Subject_.email).isNull());
```

*As far as whether or not this is considered "best practice", it is demonstrated in Oracle's Java EE Tutorial [40.3.5.1 The Expression Interface Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-criteria003.htm#JEETT00747).*

Comment: Ok, but `null` is not obligatory it's an optional value. The rest of the time I need to pass in a literal. So are you saying that the best way is to conditionally switch between my statement and yours if I detect a `null` value.

Comment: Yep, that's what I suggest. I suspect the other approaches get translated into something along the lines of `email = NULL` [which is not what you want](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null) in the case where the value passed in is `null`. You could verify this by inspecting the generated native queries.

Answer (score -1):

Null or NotNull can be used om criteriaQuery like below:

```
// IS [NOT] NULL
    Predicate n1 = cb.isNull(name);
    Predicate n2 = cb.isNotNull(name);
```

Use this link for reference : http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/comparison