# SQL Delete query non-functional

Tags: sql

I found some duplicate records in my database table called Dwg_Register. Now I am running the following query to delete them.

`Delete 
FROM PIMS.dbo.Dwg_Register 
WHERE 
Dwg_Ref = 'NULL' AND Title = 'NULL' AND [Status] = 'Approved As Noted'`

I can clearly see that there are 16 duplicate records found in the table having these fields mentioned in the above query repeating ... but when I execute this command in SQL server .. successfully executes but result is (0) records effected.

Can someone pls explain what is actually goin on in SQL server.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use `='NULL'`, use `Dwg_Ref is null`, etc.  The way you have it written it looks like you have a string value of `'null'`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL is null and = null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
DELETE FROM PIMS.dbo.Dwg_Register
WHERE Dwg_Ref IS NULL
AND Title IS NULL
AND [Status] = 'Approved As Noted'
```

When selecting `NULL` values in SQL you must use `IS NULL` instead of `= 'NULL'`

Answer (score 0):

Use `IS NULL` instead of `= 'NULL'`

`= 'NULL'` will try to match with string NULL

Comment: Very well explained. Thanks