# How to set the default value for a parameter of a integer type in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored produre like following. If I modified 
`IF (@id!=0)` to

```
IF (@id!=null)
```

When I pass a id like 200, `IF (@id!=null)` will return false, the insert part will be executed. Why? Should I modifiy `@id as int=null` to `@id as int=0`?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spname]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @id as int=null,
    @vendorName as varchar(150)=null
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    IF (@id != 0) -- update
    BEGIN
        ...
    END
    ELSE -- insert
          BEGIN
    ... 
          END
END
```

Comment: an `int` will always be `0` never be `null` so in your case it will never get hit.

Comment: Use `Is Null` or `Is Not Null` to test for `Null`; `=` and `!=` won't work. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9581790/124386

Comment: I stand corrected! Richard is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL, you cannot test for `Null` using the `=` or `!=` operators. You must use `Is Null` or `Is Not Null` instead.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spname]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @id as int = null,
    @vendorName as varchar(150) = null
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    IF @id Is Not Null -- update
    BEGIN
        ...
    END
    ELSE -- insert
    BEGIN
    ... 
    END
END
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9581790/124386

Answer (score 0):

Use `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` before writing any SP,

Or

Go Database Properties>>Options,set `ANSI NULLS Enabled` Make it true for the required Database.

`IF(@ID != 0)` would work.