# Select statement And If/else statement

Tags: sql, oracle, null, case

Sorry I am new in PL/SQL toad for oracle. I have a simple problem. I need to find some column name in this table "JTF_RS_DEFRESOURCES_VL" and i do that with this script. just an example column.

```
SELECT column1, 
       column2, 
       column3, 
       column4, 
       column5, 
       end_date_active 
FROM   jtf_rs_defresources_vl
```

Then i want to use "if else statement" that if END_DATE_ACTIVE = null then it is active else it is inactive.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9581790/139010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a CASE statement

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN end_date_active IS NULL 
             THEN 'Active'
             ELSE 'Inactive'
         END) status,
       <<other columns>>
  FROM jtf_rs_defresources_vl
```

Comment: thank you so much sir. can you explain what is the use of "case"?

Comment: case statement will compares an expression

Comment: @DontStopLearning - `CASE` is the way you implement IF/THEN logic in SQL.  `IF` statements are valid in PL/SQL but not in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` expression like @Justin suggested, but in Oracle there's a simpler function - `NVL2`. It receives three arguments and evaluates the first. If it **isn't** `null` the second argument is returned, if it is, the third one is returned.

So in your case:

```
SELECT NVL2(end_date_active, 'Active', 'Inactive') AS status,
       <<other columns>>
  FROM jtf_rs_defresources_vl
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select case end_date_active 

   when is null then 'ACTIVE',

   else 'INACTIVE'

   end as 'STATUS'
```

from jtf_rs_defresources_vl ;

Comment: You should developed your answer instead of posting one unexplained.