# How to delete a row in SQL based on a NULL condition

Tags: sql, null

I just started learning SQL; I've created a table. Learned insert command and inserted values in 2 rows. However I've inserted null values in 3rd.

Now I want to delete the third row which has 2 columns with no values in it.

I'm using the following query:

```
delete employee where city=null;
```

It doesn't seem to be working!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL is null and = null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According **SQL 92** standard many logical operations with *null values* like

```
   > null
   = null
  and null
   or null
  not null
```

should *always return null* (and *never true*). Some DBMS (e.g. Oracle) follow this rule rigorously, some (MS SQL) can have a mode that `null = null` returns *true*, not required *null*. In order to be *compartible with SQL 92* and so with (almost) all DBMSs, you should use `is null` or `is not null` standard comparisons, in your case

```
  delete from employee 
        where city is null -- <- Standard comparison
```

Answer (score 4):

You need the `is null` "operator":

```
delete from employee where city is null;
```

This is because in SQL, *nothing* is equal to `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use = with NULL. Instead, use:

```
delete employee where city is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

**To achieve this**
you will have to write this query

```
DELETE from table_name WHERE city IS NULL;
```

this query will delete the rows/records WHERE city is null

Comment: i'm sorry i didnt saw the answer :(

Answer (score 0):

Here you know you have added `Null` in city column so checking with `is null` will work but it's also possible to add an empty string in city column. So if your business condition is like delete all records from employee table where city is either null or empty i.e. with no values you should write as:

```
delete from employee where isnull(city,'')='';
```

Answer (score -3):

change it :

delete from **table_name** where city is null

or

delete from **table_name** where city = null

Comment: The from is not needed (at least in SQL Server), and your second option has the same problem: Equality always shows false when something is compared to NULL.