# Filtering with Listboxes in Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Setup: Microsoft Access 2010 (at the moment nothing else is possible) with a projects table containing `projectName` (text) and columns for `statusID` (integer) and `generationID` (integer) amongst others. The integer columns refer to their respective tables where I can retrieve their short and long names.

Goal:

A form where I/the user can select the name of a certain generation in a listbox and the form will then present all the projects with the selected generation. In real life this is a bit more complex as there are a few more columns of course. ;-)

After filtering the values I need to create reports which should then be exported as PDF

The goal (Form, Reports everything) was achieved with LibreOffice Base using subforms and a filter table. I have working code for the SQL query which did everything. But ooBase it out of the question.

```
SELECT "ftse"."stateTextShort", "ftgn"."genName", IFNULL( "p"."projGen", 9999 ) AS "pGn",
FROM "01_Projects" AS "p", "filterTable" AS "fT"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "10_State" AS "s" ON "p"."projState" = "s"."stateID"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "20_Generation" AS "g" ON "p"."projGen" = "g"."genID"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "10_State" AS "ftse" ON "fT"."filterState" = "ftse"."stateID"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "20_Generation" AS "ftgn" ON "fT"."filterGen" = "ftgn"."genID"
WHERE "pIx" = IFNULL( ( SELECT "filterProjIndex" FROM "filterTable" ), "pIx" )
AND "pSe" = IFNULL( ( SELECT "filterState" FROM "filterTable" ), "pSe" )
ORDER BY "p"."projName" ASC
```

I hope I didn’t generate complete garbage with that SQL statement as it was a whole lot longer and included lots more columns.

Question:

- I cannot use `IFNULL` or `COALESCE` in my version of Access. How do I ignore filters with no values?
- Is the approach using the filter column the right one?
- How do I realize the query above in Access. I generated the following: **SOLVED**

[break for formatting. I'm a newb and didn't know better]

```
SELECT ps.prjNameIntern, ss.stateShort, gn.genShort
FROM 001_projects AS ps
LEFT JOIN 010_status AS ss ON ps.prjStateID = ss.stateID
LEFT JOIN 020_generation AS gn ON ps.prjGenID = gn.genID
WHERE ps.prjStateID=(SELECT [ft].[fltrState] FROM [999_filterTable] AS ft)
```

But with the two JOIN statements it doesn’t work. Once I leave out the second or first one and the corresponding column it works fine. **SOLVED**

Lots of questionmarks …

UPDATE:

Ok, I now got the multiple  `JOIN` statements working. I stumbled across the differences of the draftview and the SQL-View and didn't understand Access's style of parenthesis.

The question that still remains is how to solve the absence of `IFNULL` and `COALESCE` directly in the SQL without the use of VBA.

I tried something like the following bit of code to test the use of `CASE` or `IIF`

```
SELECT fr.fltrState, fr.fltrPltf,
CASE WHEN fr.fltrPltf = 0 THEN 9999 ELSE fr.fltrPltf END
FROM 999_filterTable AS fr
```

But I just gives me: `Syntaxerror (missing operator) in statement...`

I now have

```
SELECT
IIF(fr.fltrState=0, 9999, fr.fltrState) AS IIFState,
IIF(fr.fltrGen=NULL, 9999, fr.fltrGen)  AS IIFGen
FROM 999_filterTable AS fr
```

which returns the value of `fltrState` but it doesn't return 9999 in case the column is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
SELECT IIF(fr.fltrState=0 or fr.fltrState IS NULL, 9999, fr.fltrState) AS IIFState,
       IIF(fr.fltrGen IS NULL, 9999, fr.fltrGen)  AS IIFGen
FROM 999_filterTable AS fr
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It does work. But why? I tried it with `=0` and I tried it with `=NULL` but didn't think of `IS NULL`. That's one thing. The other is the difference you make between `fltrState` and `fltrGen`. For the first you have the `or` for the latter only `IS NULL`. Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Good question. Here's is the accepted SO answer (Because the result of any arithmetic comparison with NULL is also NULL, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such comparisons) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null . As for the second comparison, I did not include the = 0 test because it wasn't included in the question. You can of course make this test if it is meaningful to your data.