# The Null Value -- different results in Sql syntaxes

Tags: sql, null

I have 2 different queries (with different purposes) working perfectly but there is something I can not grasp yet about the **Null** value

Here is one query:

```
 select NCLI , LOCALITE , CAT 
 from CLIENT
 where CAT not in (’B1’,’C1’)
 or LOCALITE not in (’Lille’,’Namur’);
```

It shows exactly what I want **Including** the rows where CAT has a null value.
Now this seems perfectly logical to me.

The only thing that disturbs me is that the query below only worked when I specified I did wanted the null rows in CAT to show up

```
select NCLI , LOCALITE , CAT from CLIENT
where CAT <> ’C1’
or CAT is null
or LOCALITE = ’Namur’;
```

When I don't add -- `or CAT is null` -- the null values don't show up. Could someone tell me what I'm not grasping here yet? Thanks.

Comment: All comparisons return `NULL` -- which is treated as false -- when one or both arguments are `NULL`.  Except for `IS NULL`.

Comment: So many duplicates, but I think I like [the answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null) best.