# why this MYSQL query return null?

Tags: sql

Why does this query always return NULL?

```
SELECT (Supervisor IS NULL) = (Supervisor = NULL) FROM Salespeople
```

is it because we specify the second half with equal to null ?

Comment: Why is this a Java question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL is null and = null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null)

Answer (score 2):

`Supervisor IS NULL` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

`Supervisor = NULL` always returns `NULL`.

Thus, `TRUE = NULL` or `FALSE = NULL` will *always* return `NULL`.

That's why your query will return `NULL` rows whose count will be the total row-count of your table.

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bb802/1).