# SQL query for column (with values contained) registering as null

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Query returns what I expected it to return now with is null instead of != null,  but I am still stuck as to why I am getting the exception in my c# application which is my main problem, Thanks

I have a column called UserId in a table WT_Users when I run the query

```
'select UserId from WT_Users;'
```

It returns a list of usersIds 1,2,3,4 which is fine but when I run the query

```
'select UserId from WT_Users where UserId != null'
```

No values are returned even thought I know that there are values held within the column. I ran these queries because I was originally working on a c# application and when I ran a reader with the first query above i got an exception 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' when i tried to pull the value from the reader, even thought I have a 'HasRows' check and 'while read' check that were satisfied

```
    SqlCommand findContactID = new SqlCommand("select UserId from WT_Users",       con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr7 = findContactID.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr7.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr7.Read())
            {
                userIDs.Add(Convert.ToString(dr7.GetInt32(0)));
            }
        }
```

In visual studio I can even see that the reader does contain the values I what under Results view.

I have spent too much time already trying to figure this out and its probably something obvious. Thanks

Comment: Use `IS NOT NULL` instead of `!= null`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL is null and = null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null)

Comment: Sorry ya the query works fine now thanks but I am still getting the exception in the c# application

Comment: It would help if you posted the error + stack trace.  For all we know, it could be `userIDs` that's `null`, which would have nothing to do with your reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use comparison operations with `null`. Use `is null` or `is not null`.

Whenever you use a comparison operator with `null`, it resolves to UNKNOWN, which is neither `True` nor `False`.

```
select UserId from WT_Users where UserId is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void Test2(SqlConnection con)
{
    var userIDs = new List<String>();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select UserId from WT_Users", con))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (r.Read())
            {
                var o = r[0];
                if ((o != null) && (o != DBNull.Value))
                {
                    userIDs.Add(o.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```