# Why Blank space is accepted and null keyword is not accepted

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

This is the **Query**

```
Select * from tblNewsLetterPetLookup where Category != ''
```

which is running ok, but whenever i am using

```
Select * from tblNewsLetterPetLookup where Category != null
```

It neither shows error nor the anticipated data,

The Column Category is declared as varchar(50)

I just want to know the reason why it is behaving such!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: because NULL is different from string you have to specify another condition for NULL https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null

Comment: Use  "Select * from tblNewsLetterPetLookup where Category IS NOT null"