# How to know if my variable datetime is null?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to compare if my variable datetime is NULL, but it doesn't work, I'm new making comparising in SQL, so could someone said me how is the good way. This is my code:

```
declare @FechaInicial datetime 
set @FechaInicial = (select FecharIncialDescarga 
                     from Contenedores where Id_Contenedor=@IdContenedor)

if(@FechaInicial = NULL) ---
    begin
    end
```

Comment: Try if @FechaInicial is NULL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL is null and = null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null)

Comment: So you say that you googled for that but you couldn't find anything about it, so the best option was to ask here?

Answer (score 3):

The direct answer to your question is `is null`:

```
if (@FechaInicial IS NULL)
```

This is because almost any comparison to `NULL` returns `NULL`, and `NULL` is treated as false.

However, I want to point out that you might really intend this logic:

```
if (not exists (select 1 from Contenedores where Id_Contenedor = @IdContenedor))
begin 
    . . .
end;
```

Although there is nothing wrong with assigning the value to a variable and checking for `NULL`, this is clearer and can be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with `if(@FechaInicial IS NULL)` as below.

```
declare @FechaInicial datetime 
set @FechaInicial = (select FecharIncialDescarga from Contenedores 
                     where Id_Contenedor=@IdContenedor)

if(@FechaInicial IS NULL) ---
    begin
    end
```

If you want to check `NULL` and also `empty`, you can try `if(ISNULL(@FechaInicial, '') = '')` as below.

```
declare @FechaInicial datetime 
set @FechaInicial = (select FecharIncialDescarga 
                     from Contenedores where Id_Contenedor=@IdContenedor)

if(ISNULL(@FechaInicial, '') = '') ---
    begin
    end
```

Also a `recommendation`, Instead of a `SET` used above, you can refactor it as below with a `SELECT`

```
SELECT @FechaInicial = FecharIncialDescarga 
FROM Contenedores WHERE Id_Contenedor = @IdContenedor
```