# Delete specific records on MSSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to delete specific records from a table using where clause but unable to do so. The command executes successfully but says zeros rows are modified.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AB1B.png)

[image]

I'm still in the starting stage of learning SQL. Thanks for helping out

Comment: `DELETE FROM PATIENT WHERE PatientCountry IS NULL`

Comment: Be careful, it will delete not a specific record but all records matching the `IS NULL` condition.

Comment: OMG! that simple can you tell me whats the difference between 'is' and '=' in that statement.

Comment: A good explanation of IS NULL, IS NOT NULL versus comparison operators is discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`= NULL` never returns true -- almost all comparisons with `NULL` return `NULL`, which is treated as false.  The correct logic is `IS NULL`:

```
delete from Patient
    where PatientCountry is null
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want find or delete null values then dont use "=" but "is".
It should be:

```
delete from patient where patientcountry is null;
```