# SQL to join two tables with one where clause on one table

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables as the following

```
table1
main_id main_val main_sub main_pk
1             A   NULL     3
3             A    1       3

table2

col_id  col_val
1           A

select table1.main_pk from table1 ,table2 WHERE
table1.main_id = table2.col_id
and table1.main_val = table2.col_val
and table1.main_sub = null
```

Am expecting the above query to select the first row in table 1 as main_sub is null and the other two columns matches. But it does not. I am just learning SQL basics so am not sure where am going wrong. Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL is null and = null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL is a little weird about `NULL` values. Use the condition

```
....
table1.main_sub IS NULL
```

for testing for a null specifically. The idea is that NULL is supposed to be interpreted as nothing, so `nothing -equals- nothing` can't ever be true because you can't compare something that doesn't exist.

Comment: in fact I know that. I can't believe how I overlooked it. Thanks guys...

Answer (score 3):

I didn't fully understand the question but I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT * from table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table1.main_val=table2.main_val WHERE table1.main_sub IS NULL
```

If not I think it directs you in the right path

Comment: Yes - the key piece here is using `is null` rather than comparing `null` for equality, which doesn't work.