# MySQL Left outer join on Knex not returning correct data

Tags: mysql

I'm troubleshooting some errors encountered in Knex, and am trying to do a left join with 2 tables, namely, notifications and metadata, with both these tables having the same 2 columns, 'device_id' and 'channel' that I would like to match. However, the below query string doesn't work and returns the following even though there is a metadata record (metadata_id=1) with matching device_id and channel.

I checked that the datatypes are also the same for device_id and channel in both tables. Been stuck for some time and not sure what is wrong here, would be great if someone can help! Also having some problems with translating to Knex for nested queries, but this is probably a small problem.

```
{
    notification_id: 1,
    message: 'hello world',
    mode: 'email',
    metadata_id: null,
    unit_conversion: null
}

SELECT `notifications`.`notification_id`, `notifications`.`message`, `notifications`.`mode`, 
  `metadata`.`metadata_id`, `metadata`.`unit_conversion` from `notifications` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `metadata` ON (`metadata`.`device_id` = `notifications`.`device_id` AND 
  `metadata`.`channel` = `notifications`.`channel` AND `metadata`.`deleted_at` = null )
  WHERE `notifications`.`notification_id` = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`metadata`.`deleted_at` = null should be replaced with `metadata`.`deleted_at` is null, with the excellent explanation by Bohemian here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9581790/6597774