# Get all data where column is null, not null and both (null and not null)

Tags: sql-server

When @se_withsiddhi='Y' I am getting all the data but when @se_withsiddhi=null want to retrieve only null values but not getting.

```
   declare @se_withsiddhi varchar
        set @se_withsiddhi = 'Y'
    select  JD.Job_No,
            INV.Bill_No,
            inv.BilledToSE 
    from    invoice INV
            left outer join Job_Details JD on JD.Job_ID = INV.Job_ID 
    where   JD.Job_No is not null 
            and INV.Bill_No is not null 
            AND isnull(INV.BilledToSE,'') = case @se_withsiddhi
                                            when 'Y' then isnull(INV.BilledToSE,'')
                                            when Null then ''
                                            else  null
                                            end`enter code here`
```

Comment: You must write:  @se_withsiddhi IS NULL

Comment: [Recommended] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use isnull for `@se_withsiddhi`:

```
case isnull(@se_withsiddhi, '')
when 'Y' then isnull(INV.BilledToSE,'')
when '' then ''
else  null
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AND 
( 
   @se_withsiddhi='Y' or 
   @se_withsiddhi is null and INV.BilledToSE is null
)
```