# MySQL Query returning "Empty Set", Why?

Tags: mysql, sql

Why does the following query return an empty set?

```
SELECT * 
   FROM null_test_tab 
   WHERE col1 = NULL
   ORDER BY id
```

Result:

```
Empty set
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL is null and = null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression should be `col is null`. The result of an arithmetic comparison with `null`, such as `col = null`, is null.

Take a look at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM null_test_tab 
 WHERE col1 IS NULL ORDER BY id
```

Here,NULL means “a missing unknown value”.

To test for NULL, use the IS NULL and IS NOT NULL operators.

You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL.

For more details check the following from mySQL doc

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html