# Cannot insert 'NULL' value into SQL Server column

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

I have a table that is filled using a stored procedure. This stored procedure uses a view that calls attributes from another databases.

To illustrate, it is something like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE theSp
AS BEGIN
     INSERT INTO dbo.theTable (attr1, att2, amount, attr4)
         SELECT attr1, attr2, amount, attr4
         FROM theView
END
```

The view is defined this way:

```
select attr1, attr2, amount, attr4
from db1.theTable
where date >='anyDate'
```

and the values are correctly inserted, but if the view is used this way:

```
select attr1, attr2, amount, attr4
from db2.theTable
where date >='anyDate'
```

this message is shown:

> Checking identity information: current identity value '1252'.
>   DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
>
> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure theSp, Line 16
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'amount', table 'db2.dbo.theTable'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Note: the 'amount' attribute for  db1 and db2 tables allows null but I never insert null, instead, I insert 0.

So I filtered to check whether the amount attribute is null and I did not get results, meaning there are not nulls value in the amount attribute.

Does anyone know a possible solution?

Comment: Have you tried ISNULL([your_column],0) ?

Comment: *"Note: The 'amount' attribute for db1 and db2 dbs tables allows null but I never insert null, instead, I insert 0."* Maybe you always make sure you insert `0` instead of `NULL`, but *someone* has inserted a `NULL`. If the column really shouldn't include `NULL` values, then it should be declared as `NOT NULL`. I would suggest that if you tried to change that attribute of `db1.theTable.amount` to `NOT NULL` the change would fail, due to rows have the value `NULL`.

Comment: I think you might have removed essential information in your attempt to make the question as concise as possible (which is a good goal). Because there are 2 things clear from the error you have posted; 1) You are definitely trying to insert into a column which **doesn't** allow nulls - there is not other way you can get that error, 2) You are definitely getting a null result from your insert query, again there is no other way you can get that error. So really its a case of investigation to find why/how those 2 events are happening.

Comment: Thanks the problem was solved by using ISNULL([theColumn], 0), I see it is not possible to know which record had the NULL attribute this way: select * from table where amount=NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the error message that you have posted

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'amount', table 'db2.dbo.theTable'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

there is a `Null` value for `amount` column in `db2.dbo.theTable'. You can use [ISNULL()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to get rid of this issue.

If you want to see the `NULL` values, you gotta use query like

`select * from db2.dbo.theTable where amount IS NULL`

Have a look at [is Null vs =Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null) to see why you weren't seeing those null records in your previous query.

Answer (score 0):

Good to have a logger to validate the condition when it's going wrong, like printing the values before inserting