# How does De Morgan's Law work in conditional SQL querying?

Tags: sql, syntax, logic, demorgans-law

Context: I was practicing some SQL questions on stratascratch.com when I came across this one:

[image: De Morgan's laws in SQL]

https://platform.stratascratch.com/coding-question?id=9648&python=

The hint says that "Drafted means `pickround` value (`int64` type) is not `NULL` or `0`. According to my understanding, this means `pickround` value must be `NOT NULL` `OR` `NOT 0`, which is the standard solution to the question. Hence, by De Morgan's Law, this means the equivalent expression is `NOT (NULL AND 0)`. However, the code I wrote there reads `pickround` is `NULL OR 0`, which is the opposite of what the question specified and still my code turned out to be correct, as indicated by the green "Solved" tick mark.

**My question is: am I misunderstanding the SQL syntax or am I misunderstanding the logic?**

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function, it's a set quantifier. Remove the brackets to write clearer code, i.e. simply do `COUNT(DISTINCT name)`.

Comment: `IN (NULL, 0)` will only return 0 rows, no NULL rows. (NULL is not considered to be equal to NULL.)

Comment: @jarlh I understand your tip about DISTINCT. I will do that from now on. But I don't understand what you mean by "NULL is not considered to be equal to NULL"

Comment: `WHERE null IN (0, NULL)` will not return anything.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand. Why is `pickround IN (NULL, 0)` equivalent to `(pickround NOTNULL OR pickround <> '0')`

Comment: You prpbably want `... and (pickround is null or pickround = 0)`.

Comment: I understood now, looking at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null and this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp