# Writing SQL query for music database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, schema, relational-database

[Click here for schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sReaa.png)

I am not very good at SQL and i dont know if I am writing these queries correctly. My answer for each question is provided below each question. Any tips/corrections greatly appreciated.

For both question, i dont know if i wrote my WHERE clause correctly with the nested SELECT.

1. Find all tracks of type audio (MediaType.name equal to "audio") which have length longer than the average length of all other tracks with the same type

my answer:

```
SELECT *

FROM Track INNER JOIN MediaType

ON Track.MediaTypeId = MediaType.MediaTypeId

WHERE Track.Milliseconds > (SELECT AVG(Milliseconds) FROM Track)

AND MediaType.name = 'audio'
```

2. Find name(s) of the customer(s) from US that do not belong to a company and who have overall paid the most of any US customers

my answer:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName

FROM Customer INNER JOIN Invoice

ON Customer.CustomerId = Invoice.CustomerId

WHERE Customer.Country = 'US' AND Customer.Company = null AND Invoice.Total = (SELECT MAX(total) FROM Invoice)
```

Comment: If your code performs what you want it to, the question is *off-topic* here and should be asked on [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If it doesn't perform what you want it to, you have to specify what are the differences between expected results and actual results, as well as any errors your code might output.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use `is null` instead of `= null` in the second query if customers who do not belong to a company have customer null in the `Customer.Company` column.

Check out this thread: [SQL is null and = null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null)

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. Regarding the correctness of my code with respect to the questions and schema, in your opinion does my answers satisfy the question requirements?

Comment: Yes, otherwise this solution looks correct. Please upvote.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your first answer mentioned :

> ...which have length longer than the average length of all other tracks **WITH THE SAME TYPE**

So your subquery in `where` condition should be `AVG(Milliseconds)` of 'Audio Type'

```
SELECT *

FROM Track INNER JOIN MediaType

ON Track.MediaTypeId = MediaType.MediaTypeId

WHERE Track.Milliseconds > (SELECT AVG(Milliseconds) FROM Track INNER JOIN MediaType

ON Track.MediaTypeId = MediaType.MediaTypeId WHERE MediaType = 'audio')

AND MediaType.name = 'audio'
```

2. `Customer.Company = null` always returns `FALSE`. You have to change it to `Customer.Company is null`