# SQL SERVER and NULL values on not equals (<>) operator

Tags: sql-server, null, equality

I have in a where clause the following statement `COLUMN_1 <> 'O'`
But the rows that contains `NULL` on the `COLUMN_1` are not take in consideration, it is like they contain the value `'O'`.

Why is that?

Comment: SQL Server does not have a null-safe equal operator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL is null and = null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null)

Answer (score 5):

Because `NULL` does not equal, nor does *not* not equal anything, including `NULL`. `NULL <> 'O'` evaluates to UNKNOWN; which is specifically not TRUE.

If you want to evaluate with `NULL` values you need to use `IS NULL`:

```sql
WHERE (COLUMN_1 <> 'O' OR COLUMN_1 IS NULL)
```

This is also documented on both not-equal operator articles:

> ### [Not Equal To (Transact SQL) - traditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-equal-to-transact-sql-traditional?view=sql-server-ver15)
>
> Compares two expressions (a comparison operator). When you compare nonnull expressions, the result is TRUE if the left operand is not equal to the right operand; otherwise, the result is FALSE. If either or both operands are NULL, see the topic [SET ANSI_NULLS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

> ### [Not Equal To (Transact SQL) - exclamation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-equal-to-transact-sql-exclamation?view=sql-server-ver15)
>
> Tests whether one expression is not equal to another expression (a comparison operator). If either or both operands are NULL, NULL is returned. Functions the same as the [<> (Not Equal To)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-equal-to-transact-sql-traditional?view=sql-server-ver15) comparison operator.