# SQL Case statement - Null + Not Null - then return a column

Tags: sql, case

I use SQL inside a 3rd party system (So don't know the type it is)
I am trying to make a CASE work on a column using data from 2 more.

I want to display a column call `Channel` that is calculated using the following logic:

If column `O.Test` is blank and column `o.subsource` is not blank, display `'RESEND'`, otherwise display the value of column `o.Source`.

This is part of the SQL showing the `CASE` I wrote to do this:

```
select
  -- other columns
 (CASE
   WHEN o.Test = NULL AND o.Subsource IS NOT NULL THEN 'RESEND'
   ElSE o.Source
 END) o.Source AS 'Channel',
 -- other columns
```

The SQL runs with no errors but the output always shows what is in `o.Source`.

Comment: Try using `is null` instead of `= null`

Comment: A null is different from a blank (empty string) and also different from a space.

Answer (score 0):

X = NULL is not equal IS NULL X

Check this question,

[SQL is null and = null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null)

change this statement "o.Test = NULL" instead of "o.Test IS NULL"

Comment: Thanks. I have done that and RESEND replaces data in Column 3 now  for When Column1 is Blank (null) and Column 2 is not blank (not null)  (which is great and part 1 of what I need) -  But it also does it when both Column 1 and 2 are blank.  If Column 1 and 2 are blank I need the data inside Column 3 to remain as it is and not be replaced by RESEND.  Hope I make sense!!!!

Comment: @CatrinaField what is the name of your "column 3"? "blank" means the empty string `''`, not `null`? Please don't use the word "blank" when you mean "null" - they re different things. Also, don't change the question, which has been answered (ie the syntax `x = null` is *never* true). If you have additional requirements, ask a new question.