# SQL <> false not returning fields with null

Tags: sql

I am setting a field based on another field from a table with this check:

```
count(case
          when recipient_status = 'Premium' and
                    delivered_in_estimated_time_window <> false
              then 1 end)
```

If I get a value `delivered_in_estimated_time_window` as `null` I would like to count it, and only if the value is false I don't want to count it. So, for example if a row looks like this:

```
recipient_status | delivered_in_estimated_time_window
'Premium'        | null
```

Then I would like add to count 1.
Only if a row looks like this one below I don't want to count it:

```
recipient_status | delivered_in_estimated_time_window
'Premium'        | false
```

But, this seems to not count `null` fields. Why is `<> false` not working for `null` values?

Comment: Because NULL isn't equal or unequal to anything, not even another NULL. You should check for NULL with `IS (NOT) NULL`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL is null and = null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null)

Comment: so I need to have a check like this one: ```delivered_in_estimated_time_window = true or delivered_in_estimated_time_window is null```, is there a more elegant way of doing this check?

Comment: You could try `delivered_in_estimated_time_window is distinct from false`. ANSI SQL, but not so commonly supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NULL` is not true or false, it's nothing, therefore you can't check if it's true or false. If you want that `NULL` values will behave like true, you can use `COALESCE` to replace `NULL` values by true:

```
...COALESCE(delivered_in_estimated_time_window,true) <> false...
```

So, your sample will be:

```
COUNT(CASE
      WHEN recipient_status = 'Premium' AND
                COALESCE(delivered_in_estimated_time_window,true) <> false
          THEN 1 END)
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
COUNT(
    CASE WHEN recipient_status='Premium' AND
              IFNULL(delivered_in_estimated_time_window, true) <> false 
         THEN 1 
    END
)
```

As stated above, `NULL` is 'special': it isn't equal or unequal to anything else, it is just `NULL`. Wrap things in `IFNULL` or `COALESCE` or add more conditions including `IS (NOT) NULL` as suggested above.

Comment: Note that IFNULL is a product specific function, and OP hasn't specified the dbms which is used.