# How to update multiple records in one go

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to update columns of a table whose values are NULL and I want to do this for 5 rows, but I'm getting the error : `missing SET keyword`

**I am running the query in oracle SQL developer**

The query I'm using is

```
UPDATE  top(5) table_name
set col1=value1,
col2=value2,
col3=value3 where col1=null;
```

Second query I used is

```
UPDATE  table_name  
set col1=value1,
col2=value2,
col3=value3 where col1=null and rownum<=5;
```

Comment: You should not use '=' to null, change it to 'IS NULL' instead. Find more explanation here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in below way:

```
UPDATE  table_name   
set (col1,col2,col3) = (select col1,col2,col3 from table_name where col1 is null and rownum<=5) 
where col1 is null;
```