# Cannot delete a record using Mybatis

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-mapper

When conditions map contains a null value, record is not deleted.

map -> NAME:"Alise" - record deleted

map -> NAME:null    - record not deleted

```
@Delete("<script>" +
        "DELETE FROM ${dataDestinationName}" +
        " WHERE" +
        "<foreach collection=\"conditions.entrySet()\" item=\"value\" index=\"key\" separator=\"AND\">" +
        "${key}=#{value}" +
        "</foreach>" +
        "</script>")
    void deleteData(@Param("dataDestinationName") String dataDestinationName,
                    @Param("conditions") HashMap<String, Object> conditions);
```

I would like to record be deleted in both cases.

Comment: When `value` is `NULL`, the condition must be `${key} IS NULL`. See this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9581745/1261766) for why.