# null not in exhaustive list

Tags: sql, oracle, null

I have a row full of 1, 2, 3 and null. Why don't there two return the same result:

```
select * from foo where foobar not in (1, 2, 3);
select * from foo where foobar is not null;
```

The first one returns empty set, while second one works as advertised. Now I'm a bit confused :-D Is there some kind of "NULL in SQL for newbies" document anywhere? :-D

(I'm using Oracle, if that matters)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between IS NULL and =NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777230/is-there-any-difference-between-is-null-and-null)

Comment: The comparison of NULLs and other values are treated different between database management systems(DBMS). In some DBMSs there is a system setting how to treat NULLS. (I have no experience in oracle, but the output you describe is what you'd get from Microsoft SQL Server) In many DBMSs you just have to specify IS NULL in the where clause for NULL values to show up in your result. It's designed around some philosophical principle that you can't compare anything to nothing (NULL)....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because your first statement is being evaluated like this:

```
select * from foo
where foobar <> 1 and foobar <> 2 and foobar <> 3
```

"null <> 1" evaluates to null, not true/false, so nothing is returned.

Answer (score 4):

Any boolean operation involving `NULL` always fails.  If `foobar` is `NULL` then:
- The test `= 1` fails.
- But `<> 1` also fails.

This means that `NULL not in (1, 2, 3)` always fails.

It's a peculiarity of `NULL Logic` that takes getting used to at first.  `NULL` can be taking to mean `Unknown`.  Which means it might be `1`, an might might not.  It's indeterminate.

So when you ask `is NULL in the list (1, 2, 3)` the answer is ***I can't tell, it's indeterminate***.  So rather than being `TRUE` or `FALSE` the answer itself is `NULL`.

And because `NULL` isn't `TRUE`, the row has failed the test.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE T (c INTEGER CHECK (c = 1)); INSERT INTO T VALUES (NULL);` -- insert succeeds! Therefore, your assertion, "Any boolean operation involving `NULL` always fails" is false.

Comment: @onedaywhen - That's because (afaik) the actual test being carried out is for breaches of the constraint : `Raise an error if NOT(c=1)`, but then `NOT(c=1)` fails.  *[I use the term "fails" rather than "is false" to try to differentiate, but I appreciate I may not have been particularly clear in this case.]*

Comment: From the SQL standard, compare: "A table check constraint is satisfied if and only if the specified search condition is not false" ...with: "The result of the where clause is a table of those rows of T for which the result of the search condition is true." IMO using the term 'fails' is misleading, p.s. does the 'boolean operation' `NULL IS NULL` 'fail'? ;)

Answer (score 0):

`not in` is not opposite of `in`

for detail check http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2007/02/25/not-in/