# JDBC error on IS NULL condition

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, scala, jdbc

I am using JDBC from Scala using ScalikeJDBC library.

Let's take a simple query: `UPDATE "test_table" SET "test" = 1234 WHERE ("asdad" is null)`

If I pass this query directly to `psql` or execute it raw via JDBC everything works fine. But if I try to pass the `null` as a parameter, I get the following error: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"`

I pass the `null` value like this:

```
session.update("""UPDATE "test_table" SET "test" = 1234 WHERE ("asdad" is ?)""", null)
```

The `?` placeholder gets automatically converted to `$1` by ScalikeJDBC library. The executed query is shown in Scala console:

```
   UPDATE "test_table" SET "test" = 1234 WHERE ("asdad" is null)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A parameter is not allowed after `is`. You have to write `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` as fixed expressions.

What is allowed would be `= $1` and then set this placeholder to `null`, but that will not result in what you expect as a comparison with `NULL` is always `unknown`.

See related questions:

[Why does NULL = NULL evaluate to false in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843451/why-does-null-null-evaluate-to-false-in-sql-server)

[Is there any difference between IS NULL and =NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777230/is-there-any-difference-between-is-null-and-null)

Comment: Thanks. What would be the preferred way to pass "IS NULL" from user side? The simplest way I can imagine is just plain old string interpolation, but that doesn't seem like the best way.

Comment: Yep, string. It's part of the query expression, so if you want to alternate between "IS NULL" and "IS NOT NULL" based on some condition, that's probably the best way to go.

Comment: build your prepared statement using a condition. In cases you want to test on `NULL` use `IS NULL`, in other cases compose prepared statement with `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Luckily I can use query builder and just alternate between ``.where("foo IS NULL")`` and ``.where("foo IS NOT NULL")`` (pseudo-code).

Answer (score 2):

[@Janick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24934348/939860) gave a flawless explanation - except that his references are for SQL Server (which happen to agree, both use standard SQL in *this* case). [Read the Postgres manual here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparison.html)

You can still parameterize a ***single*** query with standard operators:

```
session.update("""UPDATE test_table
                  SET    test = 1234
                  WHERE  asdad = ?
                  OR    (asdad IS NULL) = ?
              )""", null, true);
```

And for any other value:

```
              ... , 123, false);
```

Be sure to observe [operator precedence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE) if you add more `WHERE` conditions.

#### [`IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparison.html)

Better yet, use this:

```
session.update("""UPDATE test_table
                  SET    test = 1234
                  WHERE  asdad IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ?
              )""", null);
```

Works for `NULL` as well as for any other value.

Comment: This is an interesting insight, thanks for the tip! Actually I need to support different database backends, e.g., MySQL, Postgres and SQL Server.

Comment: Actually, both solutions are standard SQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416789/how-to-rewrite-is-distinct-from-and-is-not-distinct-from. Sadly, not all RDBMS try to implement standard features as ambitiously as Postgres ...