# store procedure don't return any data asp.net sql server 2008 r2

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am coding a filter search functionality. that is, user will search data on the basis of
any record either datetime or name, number.

here I am also returning the data from other table. So i have implemented a inner join too.
For this purpose my store procedure is as follows-

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spFilterSearch]

@var1 VARCHAR(10),
@var2 VARCHAR(10),
@Printdate DATETIME,
@ToDate varchar(10),
@FromDate varchar(10)

AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @td DateTime SET @td=CONVERT(DATETIME,@ToDate,105)
    DECLARE @fd DateTime SET @fd= CONVERT(DATETIME,@FromDate,105)
    if(@Printdate <> NULL)
        BEGIN
            SELECT cVar1, cVar2, Printdate,
            bg.Fname AS Name
            FROM dbo.Table1 
            INNER JOIN dbo.jTable2 jt ON Table1.id = jt.id
            WHERE(cVar1 LIKE @var1+'%') AND
            (cVar2 LIKE @var2+'%') 
            AND (convert(datetime,Printdate,105)=@FPdate)
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT cVar1, cVar2, Printdate,
            bg.Fname AS Name
            FROM dbo.Table1 
            INNER JOIN dbo.jTable2 jt ON Table1.id = jt.id
            WHERE(cVar1 LIKE @var1+'%') AND
            (cVar2 LIKE @var2+'%') 
            AND (convert(DATETIME,Printdate,105)>=@fd AND convert(DATETIME,Printdate,105)<=@td)

        END

END
```

(this procedure don't return any record)
At front end
I have coded like, to send null date I have created `FPdate` `property` as  below
`public DateTime? FPdate { get; set; }`

and in this way I am using it in `search event handler`

```
if (txtPrintedOn.Text != "")
          {
              string[] dtt = txtPrintedOn.Text.Split(' ');
              objprop.FPdate = Convert.ToDateTime(dtt);
          }
          else
          {
              objprop.FPdate = null;
          }
```

and to send it in the form of parameter from the business layer I have wrote code like this-

```
if (prop.FPdate.Equals(null))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Printdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.DBNull;
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Printdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = prop.FPdate;
        }
if (prop.ToDate != null)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = prop.ToDate;
        else cmd.Parameters.Add("@ToDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.DBNull;
```

At the end Data set is being return empty. I am banging my head against the wall since many hours but not getting any clue

where I am going wrong. Please suggest a way to make it run.

Thanks

Comment: are you getting record by executing sp in ssms?

Comment: are you missing @FPdate parameter in sqlserver?

Comment: yes, try executing your procedure in management studio.

Comment: Stored procedure don't return any record.

Comment: @Mukund while typing here i made that mistake , however i m not missing any parameter

Answer (score 0):

Change SP to use following

`if(@Printdate is not NULL)`

Checkout these links -

[Is there any difference between IS NULL and =NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777230/is-there-any-difference-between-is-null-and-null)

[SQL is null and = null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null)

Use this

`cmd.Parameters.Add("@FPdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = prop.FPdate.Value;`

Comment: i have made changes as you have suggested, still this procedure don't return any record

Comment: Have you tried the sp directly in management studio? , also use `.Value` for nullable property.

Comment: yes  i did, would you please give me an example where should i add this .Value

Comment: i have also attached `Convert.DBnull' ..is it not sufficient to send null value from front end..

Comment: I think as long as procedure could not return any data, i can't get it on the front end... :)

Comment: @NikhilG , you have not answered my question, are you able to execute SP , get result from management console using `null` value as well as proper value.

Comment: yes, i m able to execute this procedure, there it don't return any data on supplying actual values.

Comment: From code , you are passing `@ToDate` as null, but in SP , there is no check for this. I think you need to add default value as `NULL` to SP params.

Comment: `USE [BMDDB]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[ProdFSearch]
  
  @var1 = NULL,
  @var2 = NULL,
  @FPdate = NULL,
  @ToDate = N'2014-09-22 00:00:00.000',
  @FromDate = N'2014-07-02 00:00:00.000'
  

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value

GO`

Comment: I expect, you would be doing `ExecuteReader` and save that in `DataReader` and used `.Read` to read those!, are you getting any SQL error for this?

Comment: ArindamNayak sir, I have also `Convert.DBnull` ..is it not able to supply `null value` as `NULL`

Comment: it is `SqlDataAdapter` ...!!

Comment: You can directly pass `null` and try!

Comment: If this date value is creating any problem N'2014-07-02 00:00:00.000'??

Comment: i have made all parameters as =NULL and still it don't yield any result

Comment: If you are not getting SQL error , while executing and filling, then there can be either issue in code which executes SP or Filling data adapter, if you can post FULL  code, that will be helpful.

Comment: would you please provide me your email id where i can reach to you. thanks! or add me as nikhilbs09@gmail.com