# Oracle: CASE equivalent of DECODE

Tags: sql, oracle, case, decode

I am having problem in writing (and understanding) CASE equivalent of DECODE for the example below.

Lets say we have the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
    first_name VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT nn_first_name NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT nn_last_name NOT NULL,
    sex VARCHAR2(1) CONSTRAINT check_sex CHECK(sex IN ('M', 'F')),
    ID VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT pk_ID PRIMARY KEY,
    boss_ID VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT fk_ID_empl_to_empl REFERENCES Employee(ID)); 

Name       Null     Type         
---------- -------- ------------ 
FIRST_NAME NOT NULL VARCHAR2(15) 
LAST_NAME  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(15) 
SEX                 VARCHAR2(1)  
ID         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(15) 
BOSS_ID             VARCHAR2(15)
```

Now, I woud like to run a report which displays information about bosses and subordinates of male employees. In case if employee does not have a subordinate, then it should display (null), same goes for an employee who does not have a boss - boss of the whole company.

The above can be achieved using DECODE:

```
SELECT E1.last_name Boss,
    E2.last_name Subordinate
FROM Employee E1 FULL JOIN Employee E2
    ON E1.ID = E2.boss_ID
WHERE
    DECODE(E1.ID, NULL, 'M', E1.sex) = 'M' AND
    DECODE(E2.ID, NULL, 'M', E2.sex) = 'M';
```

The above function will change all `NULL` values into `'M'` and match rows where `'M' = 'M'` for '`Boss`' and '`Subordinates`' columns.

I am unable to write equivalent statement using `CASE`. The one I got:

```
SELECT E1.last_name Boss,
    E2.last_name Subordinate
FROM Employee E1 FULL JOIN Employee E2
    ON E1.id = E2.boss_id
WHERE
    (CASE
    WHEN E1.ID = 'NULL' THEN 'M' ELSE E1.sex END) = 'M' 
    AND
    (CASE 
    WHEN E2.ID = 'NULL' THEN 'M' ELSE E2.sex END) = 'M';
```

I seem to be misunderstanding usage of `CASE` as it returns less rows - without `(null)` values.

Comment: Use `IS NULL` . Do not compare using `= 'NULL'` or `=NULL`

Comment: [Is there any difference between IS NULL and =NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777230/is-there-any-difference-between-is-null-and-null)

Comment: Thank you! That solved a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT E1.last_name Boss,
    E2.last_name Subordinate
FROM Employee E1 FULL JOIN Employee E2
    ON E1.id = E2.boss_id
WHERE
    (CASE
    WHEN E1.ID is null THEN 'M' ELSE E1.sex END) = 'M' 
    AND
    (CASE 
    WHEN E2.ID is null THEN 'M' ELSE E2.sex END) = 'M';
```

When comparing a value to null, use IS NULL and IS NOT NULL .

[You can read about it here.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `case` or `decode` for this:

```
WHERE (E1.ID IS NULL OR E1.sex = 'M') AND
      (E2.ID IS NULL OR E2.sex = 'M')
```

Your logic would work as well, except that you have put the `NULL` in single quotes.  The string values with four characters N,U, L, L is not the same as the built-in value `NULL`.