# SQL WHERE is misplaced?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to select rows from database where the `ArkivDate` is null.

I tried this:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    [Bums].[dbo].[Items] 
INNER JOIN 
    [Bums].[dbo].[ItemsArkivFormUsed] ON [Bums].[dbo].[ItemsArkivFormUsed].[ItemNumber] = [Bums].[dbo].[Items].[ItemNumber] 
WHERE 
    [Bums].[dbo].[ItemsArkivFormUsed].[ArkivDate] = null
```

The query works if I remove the `WHERE` clause, but when I include it, the result returns empty.

I'm wondering, have I misplaced the `WHERE`?

The tables does have some null `ArkivDate` but my query can't filter to only display them

Can I anyone help me please

Comment: WHERE col IS NULL, not = NULL

Comment: And [Is there any difference between IS NULL and =NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777230/is-there-any-difference-between-is-null-and-null)

Comment: This kind is easily one of the most frequently asked questions. Folks at SO  should pop up the answer before anyone gets to post this question :)

Comment: @Mihai Thank you it is working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` is a strange beast in sql, you need to use the syntax `IS NULL` rather than `= NULL` when `ANSI_NULLS` is set to on, which is the default.

```
SELECT * FROM [Bums].[dbo].[Items] 
INNER JOIN [Bums].[dbo].[ItemsArkivFormUsed] 
    ON [Bums].[dbo].[ItemsArkivFormUsed].[ItemNumber] = [Bums].[dbo].[Items].[ItemNumber] 
WHERE [Bums].[dbo].[ItemsArkivFormUsed].[ArkivDate] IS NULL
```

See docs on [`SET ANS_NULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188048.aspx) for more info

Comment: Thank you, it is working now