# NULL not matching in join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 2 table A and B

**table A**

```
subgroup    |   maingroup   |   
------------------------------------------  
NULL        |   A       |   
NULL        |   A       |   
Top     |   B       |   
Top     |   B       |
```

**table B**

```
subgroup
---------------     
top             
NULL
```

I am running this query.

```
select * from a
join b
on a.subgroup=b.subgroup
group by a.subgroup,a.maingroup,b.subgroup
```

I am getting this output

```
subgroup    |   maingroup   |   subgroup    
------------------------------------------------------- 
Top     |   B       |   Top
```

My concern is why NULL is not matching and giving me output like
NULL    A   Null.

I am using MSSQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between IS NULL and =NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777230/is-there-any-difference-between-is-null-and-null)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the `NULL` values from your two tables to match up during the join, one option is to add an explicit condition in your `ON` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM a INNER JOIN b
    ON a.subgroup = b.subgroup OR (a.subgroup IS NULL AND b.subgroup IS NULL)
GROUP BY a.subgroup, a.maingroup, b.subgroup
```

The need for the explicit join condition `a.subgroup IS NULL AND b.subgroup IS NULL` is that comparing two `NULL` values for equality itself returns `NULL`, which is another way of saying the result is unknown.

Comment: You beat me to it -- here's some fiddle for you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b913c1/1

Comment: @sgeddes Appreciate you not double posting.

Comment: No worries, didn't see your post before I submitted.  Nice job.

Comment: Another way could be `ISNULL(a.subgroup,'~') =  ISNULL(b.subgroup,'~')`. But this is not recommended since it will not use any index present in `subgroup` column

Comment: @Pdrp, Yes, I thought about coalescing the `NULL` to something else, but there is always the challenge of choosing a value which is guaranteed to never appear in the actual data.

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth it to mention, that `NULL = NULL` evaluates neither to `TRUE` nor to `FALSE` but to `NULL`?

Comment: @piet.t I added this point to my answer, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the NULL values from your two tables to match up during the join, you can use the `IsNull` function.

```
SELECT *
FROM a INNER JOIN b
    ON IsNull(a.subgroup,'') = IsNull(b.subgroup,'')
GROUP BY a.subgroup, a.maingroup, b.subgroup
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple try with ISNULL function as

```
SELECT *   FROM a INNER JOIN b

ON ISNULL(a.subgroup,'') = ISNULL(b.subgroup,'')

GROUP BY a.subgroup, a.maingroup, b.subgroup
```

Comment: Assuming that you want to treat `NULL`s as `0`s or that `0` (or a different value that should be substituted) can act as a sentinel value that doesn't exist in the actual data.