# SQL Server query not returning expected row

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2016, I have one row in a table, and I am trying to craft a query to select the primary key from that row, based on two columns.

I know the information in the row, but when I include the info in the where clause it still doesn't find anything. Below is the screenshot showing the row and the query. The query returns nothing.

I also tried using the & operator, and I tried putting the 22 in '' and (). The finished column is datatype `binary(50)`, and the `DoorNum` column is datatype `int`.

[image]

```
select * 
from Dropoff 
where finished = NULL 
  and DoorNum = 22;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use "=" for NULL values. Because nothing equals NULL, not even NULL.  NULL means "Unknown"... if you can't know what's in it, you can't compare them.

Change your query to this:

```
select * from Dropoff 
where finished IS NULL and 
      DoorNum = 22;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it "is null" to check null values as below:

```
select * from Dropoff 
where finished is NULL and 
  DoorNum = 22;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `IS NULL` instead as next:-

```
select * from Dropoff 
where finished is NULL and 
DoorNum = 22;
```

Follow These:-

[SQL is null and = null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null)

[what is “=null” and “ IS NULL”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749044/what-is-null-and-is-null)

[Is there any difference between IS NULL and =NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777230/is-there-any-difference-between-is-null-and-null)

Answer (score 1):

You shoud use `Is Null` instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Dropoff 
WHERE finished is NULL and DoorNum = 22;
```

Use `Is Null`  to determines whether a specified expression/Value `is NULL`.