# Why does "<> Null" act differently than “IS NOT NULL”?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, null

I'm working on a project, I would like to know the difference between using `is not null` or `<> null` in Mysql.

Why should we use `IS NOT NULL` instead of `<> NULL`?  For when I do as in the second case, no results are found.

Example

1. Select * from table where name is not NUll;
2. select * from table where name <> NUll;

Comment: As already mentioned, NULL is not special value, but marker that value is missed. So you cannot compare one missing value with another. More details you can get from any SQL boot or even from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any difference between IS NULL and =NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777230/is-there-any-difference-between-is-null-and-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-null.html:

> In SQL, the NULL value is never true in comparison to any other value, even NULL. An expression that contains NULL always produces a NULL value unless otherwise indicated in the documentation for the operators and functions involved in the expression.

`NULL` values represent missing unknown data.

And `NULL` values **are treated differently from other values**.

For `NULL` values with comparison operators, such as `=`, `<`, or `<>` is not possible to test for .

It's rule. So you only can use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` operators instead.