# Sql identical query but showing different Result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a query in Sql server 2008.

```
select select * from program
where program_description <> null
```

But,Result of above query is blank.
whereas the below query is showing me the desired result.

```
select * from program
where program_description is not null
```

Is there any difference between them...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is "=null" and " IS NULL"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749044/what-is-null-and-is-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, = and <> do not work with null.
You have to use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL

Comment: Can we use != operator in null value comparision

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a difference. Comparing something with `null` will always result in `unknown`.

That is why you need to compare `null` results with `is null`

Comment: I want to get output of those records only in which program_description value should not be null.Can you please explain your answer more in depth.

Comment: @manojkumarsingh, `is null` means that the value is `null`. `is not null` means that the value is not `null`. `<> null` doesn't do what you expect, use `is not null` instead.

Comment: @manojkumarsingh: See [Working with NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Comment: Comparing something with `null` always results in `unknown`, not `false`. Otherwise, the filter `NOT (program_description <> NULL)` would return all rows.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: The second sentence contradicts the first: `IS NULL` is a comparison involving null that never evaluates to UNKNOWN.

Answer (score 1):

yes, the difference is -- according to standard, all operation with null return null. Including <>. The only valid way to check null value is operation 'is null'.

Comment: According to the *standard*, the result of the comparison is `unknown`, not `null`, Some implementations conflate the two concepts, other do not.

Comment: The standard includes operators `IS [NOT] NULL` and `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM` that always evaluate to TRUE or FALSE, never UNKNOWN.