# unable to select columns in select statement using where which contains null vlaues

Tags: mysql

Following is my  problem;

1. I created a table using `create table timepass(anyvalue bigint(19),name varchar(20));`
   And i inserted some null values into it.

Now the table looks like this.

```
"anyvalue" "name"
  Null     Rahul
  12       Satish
  Null     shubhanshu
```

Now when I fire the query

```
select * from timepass where name ='Rahul' and anyvalue=Null  ;
```

Or when i fire the query

```
select * from timepass where  anyvalue='Null';
```

**I dont get any result.**

I dont understand why this is happening someone pls explain..

Comment: Null is no value. You don't check to see if the value of the column is equal to no value. Rather you check the column `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 2):

try this ,

```
select * from timepass where anyvalue is null;
```

try same thing for other one as,

```
select * from timepass where name ='Rahul' and anyvalue is null
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749044/what-is-null-and-is-null) to know the difference between '= NULL' and 'IS NULL'