# Count table value by hour using sproc

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, count

In my table i have date column with default value TIMESTAMP on it. i want to count my record by every hour. i used sproc like this

```
    SELECT username, 


    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=8,1,NULL)  and (IF(docs != null))) AS '8:30  - 9:00', 
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=9,1,NULL)  and (IF(docs != null))) AS '9:00 - 10:00',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=10,1,NULL) and (IF(docs != null))) AS '10:00 - 11:00',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=11,1,NULL) and (IF(docs != null))) AS '11:00 - 12:00',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=12,1,NULL) and (IF(docs != null))) AS '12:00 - 1:00',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=13,1,NULL) and (IF(docs != null))) AS '1:00 - 2:00',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=14,1,NULL) and (IF(docs != null))) AS '2:00 - 3:00',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=15,1,NULL) and (IF(docs != null))) AS '3:00 - 4:00',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=16,1,NULL) and (IF(docs != null))) AS '4:00 - 5:00',
    COUNT(disblid) 'Total'


FROM claimloans 
group by username;
```

Without

```
and (IF(docs != null))
```

part my sproc working perfectly. i don't want to count row if row doc values is null. how can i achieve this ?

this is my working sproc

```
SELECT username, 

    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=8,1,NULL))  AS '8:30  - 9:00', 
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=9,1,NULL))  AS '9:00 - 10:00',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=10,1,NULL)) AS '10:00 - 11:00',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=11,1,NULL)) AS '11:00 - 12:00',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=12,1,NULL)) AS '12:00 - 1:00',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=13,1,NULL)) AS '1:00 - 2:00',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=14,1,NULL)) AS '2:00 - 3:00',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=15,1,NULL)) AS '3:00 - 4:00',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=16,1,NULL)) AS '4:00 - 5:00',
    COUNT(disblid) 'Total'


FROM claimloans 
group by username;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all who helped me. With your helps I made following sproc which do exactly what i want.

```
    DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `hourcounter`(IN datestamp DATE)
BEGIN
SELECT username, 

    COUNT(IF(HOUR(modifytime)=8,1,NULL))  AS '8:30  - 9:00', 
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(modifytime)=9,1,NULL))  AS '9:00 - 10:00',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(modifytime)=10,1,NULL)) AS '10:00 - 11:00',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(modifytime)=11,1,NULL)) AS '11:00 - 12:00',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(modifytime)=12,1,NULL)) AS '12:00 - 1:00',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(modifytime)=13,1,NULL)) AS '1:00 - 2:00',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(modifytime)=14,1,NULL)) AS '2:00 - 3:00',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(modifytime)=15,1,NULL)) AS '3:00 - 4:00',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(modifytime)=16,1,NULL)) AS '4:00 - 5:00',
    COUNT(docs) 'Total'


FROM claimloans 
WHERE docs != '' and DATE(date) = datestamp 
group by username;

   END
```

Thanks for all who helped me. I learn lot from your answers !!

Answer (score 0):

[Nothing is ever equal to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749044/what-is-null-and-is-null) (both `x = null` and `x != null` are always false), so you'll want to change `docs != NULL` to `docs IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: I changed it to " and docs IS NOT NULL " but it still count the null values :(

Answer (score 0):

So, this expression:

```
COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=8,1,NULL))
```

counts `1`, a hard-coded non-null expression, when the `date`'s hour is 8. If you replace the `1` with `doc`:

```
COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=8,doc,NULL))
```

the function will count based additionally on the contents of `doc`. That is, it will count the row not merely when the hour is 8 but when `doc` is not null at the same time.