# MySQL Creating a Function with conditional

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a mysql function with a condition that I certain word must be in the parameter for it to work

```
CREATE FUNCTION hello (s CHAR(20)) RETURNS CHAR(50) 
DETERMINISTIC 
IF s = NULL 
THEN RETURN CONCAT('Hello World!')
```

So if the query is

```
SELECT hello(NULL);
```

Then it should output:

```
+--------------------+
| hello(NULL)        |
+--------------------+
| Hello Hello World! |
+--------------------+
```

Otherwise there shouldn't be any rows returned

When I try to do my code above, it always return a syntax error. The thing is I 'm not really good at creating mysql functions especially if there are conditionals

**PS**

**I tried this code but I got the following error**

```
mysql> CREATE FUNCTION hello (s CHAR(20)) RETURNS CHAR(50) 
    -> DETERMINISTIC 
    -> IF s IS NULL 
    -> THEN RETURN CONCAT('Hello World!');
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function has several syntax errors:

```
 DELIMITER &&

 CREATE FUNCTION hello (s CHAR(20)) RETURNS CHAR(50) 
 DETERMINISTIC 
 BEGIN
     IF s IS NULL THEN
         RETURN CONCAT('Hello World!');
     END IF;
 END&&

 DELIMITER ;
```

- Try to define a `delimiter`
- Use `begin`, `end` in function body
- You need `end if` for `if` clause
- `= null` should be `is null`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`, not the equal sign. So change your query to:

```
IF s IS NULL 
THEN RETURN CONCAT('Hello World!')
```

Please check the answer in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749044/what-is-null-and-is-null) which explains this topic.

Comment: I tried your suggestion.. but got an error instead.. Check my updated question

Answer (score 1):

You seem to misunderstand how functions work in the `SELECT`.  You cannot filter rows using a function in the `SELECT`.

You could do something like this:

```
select hello(null) as flag
from dual
having flag is not null;
```

Note:  This is a non-standard use of `HAVING`; it is a MySQL extension.

A function should be returning a value.  So, you can write:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION hello (s CHAR(20)) RETURNS CHAR(50) 
DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN
    RETURN(CASE WHEN s IS NULL 'Hello World!' END)
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This version *explicitly* returns `NULL`, which the `HAVING` clause filters out.