# Why can't I use "where R.ApartmentID = null" to retrieve all non matching rows from the left table

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I only have a month of learning experience on sql server and I was just wondering why the first query before produces the right results (i.e. join two table and only select rows from left table that does NOT have a matching row), whereas the second query returns an empty query.

First

```
select R.Name, A.Name
from tblResident as R 
left join tblApartment as A
on R.ApartmentID = A.ID
where R.ApartmentID is null
```

Second

```
select R.Name, A.Name
from tblResident as R 
left join tblApartment as A
on R.ApartmentID = A.ID
where R.ApartmentID = null
```

Table structure

[image]

Comment: mysql or SQL Server?

Comment: i'm using sql server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is "=null" and " IS NULL"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749044/what-is-null-and-is-null)

Comment: this may sounds ignorant but does using mysql or sql server makes a difference in this incidence?

Comment: No, it's the same for every DBMS, some of them fail with an error for the 2nd condition. But why do you tag `mysql` when you use SQL Server?

Comment: @TonyStark Then please remove the mysql tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL is null and = null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**for MySQL**:

As per [MySQL Documentation on ***Working with NULL Values***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html):

> You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to
>   test for NULL. Because the result of any arithmetic comparison with
>   NULL is also NULL, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such
>   comparisons

And hence are the results you experienced.

**Examples**:

```
mysql> SELECT 1 = NULL, 1 <> NULL, 1 < NULL, 1 > NULL,
     > 1 is null, null is null, null = null;
+----------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+
| 1 = NULL | 1 <> NULL | 1 < NULL | 1 > NULL | 1 is null | null is null | null = null |
+----------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+
|     NULL |      NULL |     NULL |     NULL |         0 |            1 |        NULL |
+----------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+
```

I think the same is applicable for all other DB platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Tony,
 Good question
You are checking a null column. Basically null is nothing or empty in a simple english. You cannot use operators to select null values. Operators can be used only to match the column which has a value and not null. In this case, **is null** fucntion is to be used