# Py-postgresql: WHERE param = None not working

Tags: postgresql, py-postgresql

I am using `python3.6` and `py-postgresql==1.2.1`. 
I have the following statement:

`db.prepapre("SELECT * FROM seasons WHERE user_id=$1 AND season_id=$2 LIMIT 1)`, where season_id can be NULL.

I want to be able to be able to get the latest record with a NULL `season_id` by passing `None` as the `$2 param`, but it does not work. Instead, I need to create this second statement:
`db.prepapre("SELECT * FROM seasons WHERE user_id=$1 AND season_id IS NULL LIMIT 1)`

It must have something to do with `season_id = NULL` not working and `season_id IS NULL` is, but is there a way to make this work?

Comment: how about having an if at top i.e. `if not season_id` or vice versa?

Comment: [what is “=null” and “ IS NULL”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749044/what-is-null-and-is-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Comparison Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html):

> **Do not write expression = NULL because NULL is not “equal to” NULL.** (The null value represents an unknown value, and it is not known whether two unknown values are equal.)
>
> Some applications might expect that expression = NULL returns true if expression evaluates to the null value. **It is highly recommended that these applications be modified to comply with the SQL standard.** However, if that cannot be done the transform_null_equals configuration variable is available. If it is enabled, PostgreSQL will convert x = NULL clauses to x IS NULL.

and:

> 19.13.2. Platform and Client Compatibility
>
> **transform_null_equals (boolean)**
>
> When on, expressions of the form expr = NULL (or NULL = expr) are treated as expr IS NULL, that is, they return true if expr evaluates to the null value, and false otherwise. The correct SQL-spec-compliant behavior of expr = NULL is to always return null (unknown). Therefore this parameter defaults to off.

---

You could rewrite your query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM seasons 
WHERE user_id = $1 
  AND (season_id = $2 OR ($2 IS NULL AND season_id IS NULL))
-- ORDER BY ... --LIMIT without sorting could be dangerous 
                -- you should explicitly specify sorting
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Great. Thank you for the extra info too :)

Comment: If you don't want any result when the `season_id` param is not null and doesn't match any record: `SELECT * FROM seasons WHERE user_id = $1  AND (season_id = $2 OR ($2 IS NULL AND season_id IS NULL)`