# Efficient of SQL Update Query

Tags: sql

How to make this syntax below more efficient because i have to update more than 20 fields for one record?

```
 UPDATE TRANS SET A = @XA WHERE UNIQX = @XUNIQX AND STS_TRANS = 0 and A <> @XA
 UPDATE TRANS SET B = @XB WHERE UNIQX = @XUNIQX AND STS_TRANS = 0 and B <> @XB 
 UPDATE TRANS SET C = @XC WHERE UNIQX = @XUNIQX AND STS_TRANS = 0 and C <> @XC 
 UPDATE TRANS SET D = @XD WHERE UNIQX = @XUNIQX AND STS_TRANS = 0 and D <> @XD 
 UPDATE TRANS SET E = @XE WHERE UNIQX = @XUNIQX AND STS_TRANS = 0 and E <> @XE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop and dynamic sql like this:

```
    create table #temp (idx int identity, column_name varchar(max))
    insert #temp
    select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
    where table_name='trans' --and filter columns you want here

    declare @XUNIQX varchar(max) --set value here
    declare @itrerator int = 1
    declare @columnname varchar(max)
    while @itrerator<=(select max(idx) from #temp)
begin
    select @columnname=column_name from #temp where idx=@iterator
    exec ('UPDATE TRANS SET '+@columnname+' = @X'+@columnname+' WHERE UNIQX ='+ @XUNIQX+' AND STS_TRANS = 0 and '+@columnname+' <> @X'+@columnname+'')
set @iterator=@iterator+1
    end
```

Comment: it's working correctly but this is the same way with my code. the different is only manual typing or auto generate the name of fields. Any ideas? thanks for reply

Comment: This way the code will loop through each update regardless of how many columns you want to update

Comment: I have an idea base on your code. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine it:

```
UPDATE TRANS 
SET A = @XA
   ,B = @XB
   ,C = @XC
   ,D = @XD
   ,E = @XE
WHERE UNIQX = @XUNIQX 
  AND STS_TRANS = 0;
```

Even if A is not different @XA there will be `A` -> `A`(identity).

Please also note that `A <> @XA` could be tricky if column A is nullable: [what is “=null” and “ IS NULL”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749044/what-is-null-and-is-null)

Comment: but it still update the field A. Field A get update if all of conditions are match otherwise ignore it. Merge Replication reason. any idea? btw, thanks for reply.