# Query condition if NULL values available in column

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't understand difference between two queries, see images. 
Attention on last condition.
Mysql version is 5.7
What's the magic?

```
select distinct(pc) as aggregate 
from `installers` 
where 
    `success` =1 
    and 
    date(created_at) >= '2018-08-15' 
    and 
    date(created_at) <= '2018-08-21' 
    and 
    (free=0 or free is null)
```

(free is null or free=0)

[image]

```
select distinct(pc) as aggregate 
from `installers` 
where 
    `success` =1 
    and 
    date(created_at) >= '2018-08-15' 
    and 
    date(created_at) <= '2018-08-21' 
    and 
    free!=1
```

free!=1

[image]

Table structure

```
    CREATE TABLE `installers` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `driver_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `success` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `version` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pc` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `status` VARCHAR(180) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `error` VARCHAR(180) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `free` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `time` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `installers_created_at_index` (`created_at`),
    INDEX `installers_updated_at_index` (`updated_at`),
    INDEX `installers_driver_id_foreign` (`driver_id`),
    INDEX `installers_success_index` (`success`),
    INDEX `installers_version_index` (`version`),
    INDEX `installers_pc_index` (`pc`(191)),
    INDEX `installers_status_index` (`status`),
    INDEX `installers_error_index` (`error`),
    INDEX `installers_free_index` (`free`),
    INDEX `installers_time_index` (`time`),
    CONSTRAINT `installers_driver_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`driver_id`) REFERENCES `drivers` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=4709971
;
```

Distinct values of 'free' is NULL,0,1

Comment: `NULL` is not "not equal" to 1...nor equal to it either

Comment: Please replace the images of code with code.  It makes it easier to cut and paste into potential answers - people may need to run your code to understand or fix it...

Comment: So, (free is null or free=0) - is right query?

Comment: So, (free is null or free=0) - is right query?  - only you are in a position to make that decision.

Comment: The code in the images doesn't always match the linked code. Could you verify that they match and remove the images?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is "=null" and " IS NULL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749044/what-is-null-and-is-null)

Comment: Note about `DISTINCT` : your use of it as `distinct(pc)` betrays a possible misunderstanding that is pretty common. It is not a function or a modifier applied to a column in parens `(pc)`. `DISTINCT` is rather a keyword applied to the entire `SELECT` query, all rows deduplicated and it should be written without the parens `()` as `SELECT DISTINCT pc...`. In this case with only one column selected, it makes no difference. But I commonly see patterns like `SELECT distinct(col1), col2, col3` with an incorrect expectation for what the result will be...

Comment: Your title isn't related to your question at all. You should consider changing it to something relevant to what you're asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NULL is not the value, NULL (according to [WIKI - NULL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL))):

> Null (or NULL) is a special marker used in Structured Query Language
>   to indicate that a data value does not exist in the database.
>
> This should not be confused with a value of 0. A null value indicates
>   a lack of a value — a lack of a value is not the same thing as a value
>   of zero in the same way that a lack of an answer is not the same thing
>   as an answer of "no". For example, consider the question "How many
>   books does Adam own?" The answer may be "zero" (we know that he owns
>   none) or "null" (we do not know how many he owns). In a database
>   table, the column reporting this answer would start out with no value
>   (marked by Null), and it would not be updated with the value "zero"
>   until we have ascertained that Adam owns no books.
>
> SQL null is a state, not a value. This usage is quite different from
>   most programming languages, where null value of a reference means it
>   is not pointing to any object.
>
> Since Null is not a member of any data domain, it is not considered a
>   "value", but rather a marker (or placeholder) indicating the absence
>   of value. Because of this, **comparisons with Null can never result in
>   either True or False, but always in a third logical result,
>   Unknown.**

That is:

- `1 = 0` is  FALSE, but `1 = NULL` is UNKNOWN
- `1 != 0` is TRUE but `1 != NULL` is also UNKNOWN

The `UNKNOWN` state in WHERE clause is equivalent to FALSE. 
This is intuitive - since x is NULL (unknown), then we cannot say whether x = 1 nor x != 1 is true - in both cases the comparison result is not known.
Because of the above, there are special operators in SQL that check whether the column is null or not null -`x IS NULL` and `x IS NOT NULL`.
You can see this behaviour in this simple demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f78b0/5

```
SELECT * FROM t;
| id |      x |
|----|--------|
|  1 |      1 |
|  2 |      0 |
|  3 | (null) |
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE x =1;
| id | x |
|----|---|
|  1 | 1 |
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE x != 1;
| id | x |
|----|---|
|  2 | 0 |
```

Please note that the above query returned ony the record with `x = 2` but skipped the record with `x = NULL` because the comparison `x != NULL` evaluated to UNKNOWN, which is equivalent to FALSE.

---

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE x IS NULL;

| id |      x |
|----|--------|
|  3 | (null) |
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE x IS NOT NULL;
| id | x |
|----|---|
|  1 | 1 |
|  2 | 0 |
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE x = 1 OR x IS NULL;
| id |      x |
|----|--------|
|  1 |      1 |
|  3 | (null) |
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE x != 1 OR x IS NULL;
| id |      x |
|----|--------|
|  2 |      0 |
|  3 | (null) |
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using INT(11) your value in *free* column can be between -2147483648 and 2147483647

The default value of *free* column is *NULL* (It means unknown or not set , It does not mean 0 or any known number, Attention : NULL=NULL is always *false* because NULL is not equal NULL)

So when you use `free=0 or free is null` statement it means when free only equals to 0 or free is not set(NULL) and otherwise it is *false*

But when you use `free!=1` it is *true* when free is 0 , -1 , 4145 and ...
**Every known number but 1 AND NULL**

*PS: Both of them can be true , It depends on you what you want from your query 
If the free is 1 only when it is free and otherwise it is 0 or NULL, then `free=0 or free is null` is correct statement* But for Boolean values according to the MySQL manual you can use Bool and Boolean which are at the moment aliases of [tinyint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html):

> Bool, Boolean: These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of
>   zero is considered false. Non-zero values are considered true.

Comment: No, `free != 1` will _not_ be true when `free` is `NULL`.