# Check if a record exist return an incorrect result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `match_lineup_substitute` which have the following record:

```
player_substitute_id | player_substituted_id | match_id |
       90930                   NULL             2807486
```

I want check if the record exist, so I wrote this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `match_lineup_substitute` 
                WHERE match_id = 2807486 AND 
                player_substitute_id = 90930 AND player_substituted_id = null
```

this will return: 0

what happened?

Comment: To check for `null` values, we use `IS NULL` not `= null`

Comment: I'd avoid such similar column names. player_substitute_id and player_substituted_id  will cause trouble.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749044/what-is-null-and-is-null

Comment: `NULL = NULL` yields `NULL` which isn't `TRUE`.  `NULL IS NULL` yields `TRUE` , which is useful to you.  Most operations on `NULL` yield `NULL` and need very specific care in handling them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from

```
player_substituted_id = null
```

to

```
player_substituted_id IS NULL
```

If you want to check `null` value in field you have to use `IS NULL` in where clause.

Answer (score 1):

To check for `null` values use `is`

```
... and player_substituted_id IS NULL
```

[The DOC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you should use `IS NULL` (or `IS NOT NULL`) to evaluate if a value is (or isn't) null, instead of using arithmetic comparison operators.

In your example, you should replace

```
AND player_substituted_id = null
```

with:

```
... AND player_substituted_id IS NULL
```

---

You can read more about it in the [Working with NULL values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html) section of the official documentation.

> ...
>
> To test for NULL, use the **IS NULL** and **IS NOT NULL** operators (...)
>
> ...
>
> You **cannot** use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is not a value (see it as "value is unknown"), therefore `column = NULL` always returns `NULL`.

`NULL` `AND` something returns `NULL`

So your `WHERE` condition doesn't return `TRUE` (since it returns NULL), so the row is not selected.

Use `column IS NULL` instead.

Note that the same is true if you compare two columns : `column1 = column2`will be `NULL` for each row where `column1` or `column2` is `NULL`.

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html