# Trying to insert NULL with None as '?' placeholder not working for sqlite3 for Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm working on a database using sqlite3 for Python that stores addresses. I understand that you use `?` as a placeholder and you give the `execute` method a tuple or list of values to fill the placeholders. I am also aware that `None` should correspond to sqlite's `NULL` value.

However, if I try to `SELECT` from the table like so, even though this entry does exist in the table, it does not fetch any values:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM test WHERE (address, apartment, city, state) = (?, ?, ?, ?);',
               ('123 Front St', None, 'Springfield', 'WA'))
```

However, if the apartment is not a `NULL` value, and I give it a regular old string for the apartment, it will fetch it just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `NULL = NULL` is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rewrite query to be `NULL` safe:

```
-- ISO-standard
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE address IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ?
  AND apartment IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ?
  AND city IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ?
  AND state US NOT DISTINCT FROM ?;

-- SQLite
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE (address = ? OR ? IS NULL)
  AND (apartment = ? OR ? IS NULL)
  ...
```

---

In SQL world `col = NULL` yields Unknown which is different than true. 
Related: [what is “=null” and “ IS NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749044/what-is-null-and-is-null)

Comment: This produces a `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "DISTINCT": syntax error`. But I see that I have to use `col IS NULL` instead of `=`. Looks like I'll just have to generate one query or the other depending on whether the apartment is empty.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, the sqlite version works correctly. However, I'll probably still decide to dynamically generate the query. Having to duplicate each of the placeholder values in the tuple seems clunkier to my brain than having just one query or another.