# MySQL search for value or value = NULL?

Tags: mysql

I can't figure out how to do a filter in MySQL for a value or NULL?

Here's a simple contrived example.  We have a sports team. Multiple tables. Everybody is in the process or ordering a t-shirt. And for a contrived use case, the t-shirt manufacturer says red shirts are no longer available. We want to order a new t-shirt for everyone on the team who hasn't yet ordered or had an order for a red shirt.  And after a join, I see the following:

Post join result showing name and color choice (less any filtering):

```
Adam       red
Beth       blue
Craig      NULL
Dawn       NULL
Edith      red
Frank      blue
Gabriel    NULL
```

As part of that join, I'd really like to have just the result showing folks with red or NULL choices. I'm doing the test sql joins and WHERE filtering in a phpmyadmin panel in the browser.  The "NULL" values show up as italic characters in lighter font color.

I've tried every combination of `...WHERE 'color' = "red" or 'color' = NULL`, also `...WHERE 'color' = "red" or 'color' = ""` that I can come up with. Generally I get a empty set of values as a result.  Obviously, in the above example, I'd expect to see a list containing just `Adam, Craig, Dawn, Edith, and Gabriel` in my query results.

Is there a trick here?  Note, my actual joins are a little bit involved and the data is confidential.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between " = null" and " IS NULL"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749044/whats-the-difference-between-null-and-is-null)

Comment: You can use IS NULL handling to check the null value

Comment: @IanKemp Cha-Ching.  Success!!.  `...WHERE 'color' = "red" or 'color' IS NULL` totally nailed it..  Its sort of a repeat, but not actually asked the way I asked this one.  Do you want to create a five line answer, that I can accept, perhaps with references for use by others in the future?  Ian, first please...

Answer (score 0):

You can use IS NULL to check the null values and To filter them out, you can use IS NOT NULL
here is the reference link: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `where color= 'red' OR color is NULL` to get the required result.