# Not able to delete complete row in SQL

Tags: mysql

Wanted to delete complete row, which contains NULL entries in sql with  command

```sql
DELETE FROM student WHERE ID=NULL;
```

What is wrong in this code?

Comment: 1. Please state the specific error you are getting.
2. Please show the contents of the table - `SELECT * FROM student;`

Comment: See [What's the difference between " = null" and " IS NULL"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2749044/205233)

Comment: Take the time to look at what [NULL means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)). You are effectively saying Delete where *Id is equivalent to an unknown quantity* - which it never is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect you need to check for `IS NULL`

```
DELETE FROM student WHERE ID IS NULL;
```

Adding link to documentation thanks to [D M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14956277/d-m)

[Working with NULL values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Comment: Relevant docs are [Working with NULL values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html): "To test for `NULL`, use the `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` operators" and "You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as `=`, `<`, or `<>` to test for `NULL`."

Comment: Great!!! It worked.