# Why does column = NULL return no rows?

Tags: sql, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does NULL = NULL evaluate to false in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843451/why-does-null-null-evaluate-to-false-in-sql-server)

If you generate a query to insert the data in table "MyTab" for column --- Age, Sex, DOB, ID

```
INSERT INTO MyTab 
VALUES (22, '', '', 4)
```

What'll be the value in column Sex & DOB ?
Is it NULL ?

If value is NULL then ---

```
 SELECT * FROM MyTab
 WHERE Sex=NULL
```

above query gives output ---- no rows selected --- why ??

if value is not NULL then ---

```
 SELECT * FROM Mytab
 WHERE Sex IS NULL
```

above query gives the output ---- how ??

Comment: NULL does not equally anything.  So =NULL always returns false. And that's why there's a special syntax for testing nullness.  This is true for all ANSI SQL databases.

Comment: "What'll be the value in column Sex & DOB ? Is it NULL ?" Depends on RDBMS. In Oracle, yes it would be null. In SQL Server, no it the value would be an empty string, `''`.

Answer (score 13):

`NULL` is a special value in SQL denoting the *absence of data*. As such, you *cannot* do queries like:

```
SELECT fields FROM table WHERE column = NULL
```

`NULL` cannot be compared to anything, including `NULL` itself. Instead, you'd need:

```
SELECT fields FROM table WHERE column IS NULL
```

---

However in your case you are really inserting an empty value in `Sex` and `DOB`.
And empty value is not `NULL`. You'd have to query for:

```
SELECT fields FROM table WHERE column = ''
```

Answer (score 2):

From [Null (SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29)

> Misunderstanding of how Null works is
>   the cause of a great number of errors
>   in SQL code, both in ISO standard SQL
>   statements and in the specific SQL
>   dialects supported by real-world
>   database management systems. **These
>   mistakes are usually the result of
>   confusion between Null and either 0
>   (zero) or an empty string (a string
>   value with a length of zero,
>   represented in SQL as '').** Null is
>   defined by the ISO SQL standard as
>   different from both an empty string
>   and the numerical value 0, however.
>   While Null indicates the absence of
>   any value, the empty string and
>   numerical zero both represent actual
>   values.

Also from [SET ANSI_NULLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259229%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

> When SET ANSI_NULLS is OFF, the Equals
>   (=) and Not Equal To (<>) comparison
>   operators do not follow the SQL-92
>   standard. A SELECT statement using
>   WHERE column_name = NULL returns the
>   rows with null values in column_name.
>   A SELECT statement using WHERE
>   column_name <> NULL returns the rows
>   with nonnull values in the column. In
>   addition, a SELECT statement using
>   WHERE column_name <> XYZ_value returns
>   all rows that are not XYZ value and
>   that are not NULL.

Answer (score 2):

'' - it`s mean empty string. If you want to insert NULL,you need yo use

```
 INSERT INTO MyTab 
          VALUES (22, '', NULL, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

NULL means no data (not even blank or empty stuff), so `Column = NULL` is not going to work although `Column IS NULL` should return rows with that column as NULL. But you're inserting '' value so comparing with NULL won't return any rows.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, first query returns no output because you cannot check for NULL with equals operator. The second query is more puzzling - my only guess is that you are using Oracle which treats empty strings as NULLs.

The answer to the question about values in Sex and DOB fields would depend on the type of those fields and database engine you are working with.