# Sql query with column=null returns zero result set

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does column = NULL return no rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878954/why-does-column-null-return-no-rows)

I am trying to query a row  from mysql database where value of certain column is null, here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE mycolumn=null
```

Actually I am using Boolean column as a three way switch where 0,1 and null meant to be used for different results.

Above query is returning a zero result set and if I remove `where mycolumn=null` thing, its returning right result with some rows having null value for the specified column.

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn IS null` help? Also note that you don't need to use the ` to delineate table names if there are no spaces in the name

Comment: `WHERE mycolumn IS NULL`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Column = null will always give null

try column is null

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE mycolumn is null
```

Comment: Column = null is always false, but right answer.

Comment: Because the result of any arithmetic comparison with NULL is also NULL, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such comparisons. 

From MySQL open docs.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson `Column = null` is `unknown` not `false`. SQL uses three valued logic.

Comment: @Martin, strange way of looking at it. Would Select * From MyTable Where (Column = null) is null work then? :)

Comment: @TonyHopkinson actually it is working .. check the fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/1734/0

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - The distinction is important in check constraints (can evaluate to true or unknown but not false) and also consider negating the original expression. `WHERE NOT (mycolumn=null)` is `NOT(unknown)` which is still `unknown` (as opposed to `NOT(false)` which would be `true`). In MySQL `SELECT CASE WHEN (null = null) IS NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END` returns `Y`. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/2044)

Comment: It's a good day I learnt something. A why more than a how, but still good.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE mycolumn is null
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/working-with-null.html

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, the concept of `null` is analagous to *unknown*.  That which is unknown cannot actually be equal to anything, even another unknown.

For this reason, `X = null` and even `null = null` will never be true, as the expression itself evaluates to another null (meaning, *it is unknown if x is equal to null*.)

Instead, you can use `IS NULL` to figure out if a value is *set to* null:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE mycolumn is null
```

...or you can [coalesce](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) a null value into something else.