# Difference between ColumnName = Null and ColumnName Is Null in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the difference between `ColumnName = Null` and `ColumnName Is Null` in SQL Server? I have researched about this but I didn't get any clarification.

Actually I want to retrieve column has null value

```
Select * from Table1 where column1 is null
```

This query returning expected result but the following query not giving

```
 Select * from Table1 where column1 = null
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't SQL support "= null" instead of "is null"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078837/why-doesnt-sql-support-null-instead-of-is-null). You should also check [Why doesn't SQL support “= null” instead of “is null”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078837/why-doesnt-sql-support-null-instead-of-is-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparisons with null using normal operators are never true.

That's basically because null is "unknown" so it can't be determined whether it is or is not some value.

The special syntax `is null` and `is not null` must be used to determine nullness.

Comment: Except when ANSI_NULLS is OFF. Note:  ANSI_NULLS OFF is deprecated and  will be removed in a future version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Using [comparison](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx) operators on `NULL` will result un `Unkown result`

Take a look at the following example:

```
Declare @temp table
(
 val1 int,
 val2 int 
)

INSERT INTO @temp
VALUES (1,NULL),
       (NULL,1),
       (NULL,NULL)

SELECT CASE 
        WHEN val1 > val2 THEN 'Val 1 greater'
        WHEN val2 > val1 THEN 'val 1 smaller'
        WHEN val1 = val2 THEN 'Val1 is equal to val 2'
        WHEN val1 = NULL THEN 'val1 = NULL'
        WHEN val1 IS NULL THEN 'val1 IS NULL'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
        END result 
FROM @temp
```

this will result:

```
Unknown
val1 IS NULL
val1 IS NULL
```

Please note that changing the `ANSI_NULLS` to `OFF`, will change the behaviour of the `=` operator, and will return `TRUE` for `NULL = NULL`

Any way, IMHO (and I think the prevailing view is), The best practice is using [IS NULL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

"is null" is the proper way.  It's like the difference between <> and != for not equal.  != is the standard.

here is the Microsoft documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx

"To determine whether an expression is NULL, use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL instead of comparison operators (such as = or !=). Comparison operators return UNKNOWN when either or both arguments are NULL."

Comment: Incorrect. both do not work! (unless ANSI NULLS is changed from the default setting)

Comment: No second query dint give me result