# How to select all rows but join information under condition

Tags: sql

Simplified I have two tables **NAMES** (with columns ***ID*** and ***NAME***) and **ADRESSES** (with columns ***COUNTRY*** and ***CITY*** and ***NAME_ID***).

---

Example for NAMES:

```
1 - Hans
2 - Mark
3 - Joseph
```

Example for ADRESSES:

```
Denmark - Kopenhagen - 1
Germany - Berlin - 3
```

I need to select all Names which either have no adress at all OR with their CITY but only when their country is... Denmark.

```
SELECT
NA.NAME AS NAME,
AD.CITY AS CITY
FROM NAMES AS NA
LEFT JOIN ADRESSES AS AD ON AD.NAME_ID = NA.ID
```

now when I add something like

```
WHERE AD.COUNTRY="Denmark"
```

or

```
WHERE (AD.COUNTRY="Denmark" OR AD.COUNTRY=NULL)
```

I still only get a list of Names with Cities in Denmark but not all other Names which have no Adress/City at all.

When I remove the condition of course I get all Names and existing Cities but even in all other countries.

The desired result would be:

```
Hans - Kopenhagen
Mark - NULL
```

Comment: Try to use WHERE (AD.CITY="Denmark" OR AD.CITY IS NULL) take a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214231/difference-between-columnname-null-and-columnname-is-null-in-sql-server

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and `city = "Denmark"` is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: Move AD.COUNTRY="Denmark" predicate to ON from WHERE  to keep LEFT JOIN left. Also, `AD.CITY=NULL` is never true in SQL, use `AD.CITY IS NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean `WHERE AD.COUNTRY='Denmark'` not `WHERE AD.CITY='Denmark'`. Also, Using WHERE clause with LEFT JOIN makes it like INNER JOIN. So shift your condition to LEFT JOIN clause -

```
SELECT NA.NAME AS NAME,
       AD.CITY AS CITY
FROM NAMES AS NA
LEFT JOIN ADRESSES AS AD ON AD.NAME_ID = NA.ID
WHERE AD.COUNTRY='Denmark' OR AD.COUNTRY IS NULL
```

Comment: frist you cant compare something to null, you need `IS NULL` second you dont need the `OR` condition. the NULL is assigned after the `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, Agrees on first one and corrected the same. I just didn't notice it. For 2nd, Are you really sure, We don't need `OR` condition.

Comment: Very sure. Unless you have null on the original table you dont have null after the left join is done. So in that case you can use that check on the `WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

> I need to select all Names which either have no adress at all OR with their CITY but only when their country is... Denmark.

I believe you want:

```
SELECT NA.NAME AS NAME, AD.CITY AS CITY
FROM NAMES NA LEFT JOIN 
     ADRESSES AD
     ON AD.NAME_ID = NA.ID
WHERE AD.COUNTRY = 'DENMARK' OR AD.COUNTRY IS NULL;
```

This should not return names in other countries, such as Germany.

Comment: OP sample output show Mark from Germany but with NULL in the address.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . The desired results filter out Joseph, which directly contradicts at least three other places of explanation.  I think the specified results are not correct.  In any case, the other answers do not filter rows at all so they are not correct.

Comment: You are right, not all answer solve everything  on the question. Looks like OP is German so maybe English isn't his strong language, but seem to have found this answer.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, Joseph is from Germany not Mark. I guess you are getting confused between them.